# How to handle error "Could not load the assembly file:///C:\sample.dll. This assembly may have been downloaded from the Web."

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll

I downloaded some sample code for windows phone app. When I tried to run it in vs2010 it shows this error

**"Could not load the assembly file:///C:\Users\sample\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll. This assembly may have been downloaded from the Web."**

I changed the properties of this file and unblocked it but still it shows the same error.

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what you did to fix the DLL.  Another thing you can do is copy it to a flash memory stick and copy it back.  That will shear off the alternate data stream from the file that stores the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that for some security reason the target assembly is blocked.you have to go to the folder where the assembly is stored and unlock it by right clicking properties and then the unblock button.

Answer (score 0):

I also didn't see the unblock button on the offending dll. Moving my project to a folder outside my `Documents` folder resolved the issue for me. I use c:\myprojects\ instead of c:\users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects